# How can i merge multiple resource file into single resource file using C#.net?

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, resx, vsix

I have many resx files like :
1. test1.resx
2. test2.resx
3. test3.resx

I want Merge.resx which has all data and value of (test1, test2 and test3).

Thanks to all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess that you are looking for a merge utility described in ProjectCode site.
For your convenience providing URL to that article and source code for the tool
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37022/Solving-the-resx-Merge-Problem